# Будет ли в коде неявное приведение типов

Tags: c#

у меня есть набор разных классов, которые мне нужно положить в один список и в дальнейшем с ним работать. Я пытаюсь избежать различных приведений типов(кроме приведения к IContainer в самом начале), поэтому список с каким нибудь общим классом не подойдет. Я написал пример, который, как я думаю поможет этого достичь. Явных приведений здесь нет, будет ли здесь где-то скрыто неявное приведение?

```
public class TestCast : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private MeshFilter meshFilter;
    [SerializeField]
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    [SerializeField]
    private BoxCollider boxCollider;


    [Button]
    private void DoTest()
    {
        List<IContainer> containers = new List<IContainer>();
        containers.Add(new Container<MeshFilter>(meshFilter));
        containers.Add(new Container<MeshRenderer>(meshRenderer));
        containers.Add(new Container<BoxCollider>(boxCollider));

        for (int i = 0; i < containers.Count; i++)
        {
            containers[i].Print(this);
        }
    }

    private void Print<T>(T component) where T : Component
    {
        // Do something
        Debug.Log(component.GetType());
    }


    public struct Container<T> : IContainer where T : Component
    {
        private T component;

        public Container(T component)
        {
            this.component = component;
        }

        public void Print(TestCast testCast)
        {
            testCast.Print(component);
        }
    }

    public interface IContainer
    {
        void Print(TestCast testCast);
    }
}
```

Comment: `containers.Add(new Container ...)` - здесь происходит боксинг. Это вас беспокоит? | [Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MukulSabharwal.ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer) покажет такие места

Comment: Не создавайте публичные вложенные типы, ими потом будет пользоваться неудобно, и код такой читать непривычно, вынесите их из класса.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему при использовании:

```
where T : Component
```

будет происхоидить приведение к типу `Component`.

```
public struct Container<T>: IContainer  where T : Component
{
    private T component;

    public Container(T component)
    {
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```

Вот во что превратиться даный код в IL:

```
.class public sequential ansi sealed beforefieldinit Container`1<(Component) T> //здесь происходит приведение типа
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueType
    implements IContainer
{
    // Fields
    .field private !T component

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor (
            !T component
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2062
        // Code size 9 (0x9)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldarg.0
        IL_0002: ldarg.1
        IL_0003: stfld !0 valuetype Container`1<!T>::component
        IL_0008: ret
    } // end of method Container`1::.ctor

} // end of class Container`1
```

Так что, отвечая на ваш вопрос: здесь будут неявные приведения(`<(Component) T>`) + как было сказанно в комментариях, есть упакова при добавлении объектов в коллекцию.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin можно ли как-то в коде выделять цветом кусок кода?

Comment: `// вот это место, которое я хочу отметить особо:`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin все таки скриншотом мне кажется было бы гораздо удобнее) Вряд ли кому то нужно копировать этот IL код)